# Webpack require() retuning 136 errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

**DISCLAIMER: I'm still a new programmer, so I may get many things wrong.**

I've been trying to integrate the Sneaks-API into my web application. However, Sneaks is a node module, so I need to use a bundler like WebPack. Whenever I run my build, Webpack returns 136 errors because I use require at the beginning of my JS file.

Here is my JS file (just the demo from the Sneaks-API GitHub page):

```
const SneaksAPI = require('sneaks-api');
const sneaks = new SneaksAPI();

//getProducts(keyword, limit, callback) takes in a keyword and limit and returns a product array 
sneaks.getProducts("Yeezy Cinder", 10, function(err, products){
    console.log(products)
})

//Product object includes styleID where you input it in the getProductPrices function
//getProductPrices(styleID, callback) takes in a style ID and returns sneaker info including a price map and more images of the product
sneaks.getProductPrices("FY2903", function(err, product){
    console.log(product)
})
//getMostPopular(limit, callback) takes in a limit and returns an array of the current popular products curated by StockX
sneaks.getMostPopular(10, function(err, products){
    console.log(products)
})
```

Here is my webpack config file:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    watch: true
}
```

And here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "swipe",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "sneaks-api": "^1.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

I've tried searching for another way to use the Sneaks-API, but it seems this is the only way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the package you're using `sneaks-api` that runs on `node` env which means it can't run on `browser` env while the default `target` that `webpack` runs build against is `browser` which ends up the issue.

Hence, I guess it would work again if you set `target` accordingly in the config file as following:

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  target: 'node',
}
```

Comment: I have tried the solution and it eliminates all the VSCode code console errors (adds a few warnings), but the web console returns this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is noyt defined.

A few questions:

Will I still be able to publish this website on the web if I do this? Follow-up: Will I also be abe to use vanilla js in the same file being bundle or will I have to use a different file for node and vanilla.


Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: Hang on, like I said the package `sneaks-api` can't be run on browser env which means you can only use it at your server side (node env) only due to its dependencies which seems to use a connected `mongodb` package